# Splitting a line n number of times and storing results in a map

Tags: python, string, csv

I'm writing a script that queries a database file a multitude of times and writes the results of each query to a csv file, but I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to think of a solution for in python.

The program runs like so:
Query ->
returns a match that looks like this

```
<HEADER1|HEADER2|HEADER3|HEADER4|HEADER5>\n<id|K|X|D|Z|>
```

I then take this result, strip the headers, and convert what's leftover into a map

```
                        if matches == 1:
                            split = data.value.find("\n")
                            testLine = data.value[split:]
                            lineArray = map(str.strip, testLine.split('|'))
                            print lineArray
```

This leaves me with some like

```
['id', 'K', 'X', 'D', 'Z']
```

That I can then write to a CSV file

My problem is happening when I get a match of > 1 items, I am left with a big map that is obviously not correct as that data before conversion is returned as

```
<id|K|X|D|Z|>\n<id|K|X|D|Z|>\n<id|K|X|D|Z|>\n  ------Before conversion to map

['id', 'K', 'X', 'D', 'Z'\n<id', 'K', 'X', 'D', 'Z'\nid', 'K', 'X', 'D', 'Z'] ---Results after map conversion
```

How can I go about splitting this the correct number of ways depending on how many matches are returned, while still being able to convert it to a map so it can be written to a csv file?

Comment: Check out [`str.split()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your value on `'\n'`. Then first line is the header line, and all other lines are data:

```
if matches >= 1:
    lines = data.value.split('\n')[1:]    # split value in lines and skip first one
    for line in lines:
        lineArray = map(str.strip, line.strip('<>').split('|'))
        # append lineArray to the csv file
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the location of the first "\n" you could split by "\n".  For example

```
if matches == 1:
    for testLine in data.split("\n")[1:]:
        lineArray = map(str.strip, testLine.split("|"))
```

This is not a full solution (still need to clean up the "<" and ">"), but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have to* use a `map`. This uses a nested list comprehension:

```
data = '<HEADER1|HEADER2|HEADER3|HEADER4|HEADER5>\n<id|K|X|D|Z|>\n<id|K|X|D|Z|>\n<id|K|X|D|Z|>\n<id|K|X|D|Z|>'
values = data.split()[1:]
# get rid of leading '<` and trailing '|>':
lineArray = [ [str.strip() for str in value[1:-2].split('|')] for value in values]
print(lineArray)
```

Prints:

```
[['id', 'K', 'X', 'D', 'Z'], ['id', 'K', 'X', 'D', 'Z'], ['id', 'K', 'X', 'D', 'Z'], ['id', 'K', 'X', 'D', 'Z']]
```